# What kind of database and how to create it to hierarchically categorize text?

Tags: java, php, database, jsp, phpmyadmin

its an app that i will start from scratch .i wish to use jsp with phpmyadmin and mysql database.but i duno how should i create my database...my data is like this

img833.imageshack.us/img833/9901/89112252.png

EG Input text : "Describe the diagram below" (so describe is in Perception P1 Physchomotor Domain) the output will be : Perception p1, Physchomotor Domain

but there are 3 more domains which make it like a hierarchy where the domains are the parents of the p1,p2 and so on...how shud i build my database like this ? different domain hav different numbers of p1,p2

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what your dataset is or what it is supposed to do, but I will give you some tips.

It seems that you have "domains" which would be your object model (one table in your database).  These domains can have one or multiple parents or children, so you will want to have a column that contains the ID of the parent (this will enable you to do a query to find parents or children).  This is typically all you need for any hierarchical structure.  You will then want 1 or more columns for the data.  For instance, I think you would want to have a column called "words" which would be a list of strings perhaps stored as text or varchar datatype.

And by the way, if you want good help, you should try to make your question more clear, and use good spelling and grammar.  People like helping more when a question is framed properly.